# Deleting Document From FIRESTORE DB from using JAR Fails

Tags: java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am dealing with a very strange problem.

I have a code developed on IntelliJ which tries to delete a document from FireStore DB.

When I run the main() inside IntelliJ, there is no problem.

But when I create JAR of this project and run this jar as "java -jar xxxxx.jar", I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
        at com.google.api.gax.retrying.BasicRetryingFuture.<init>(BasicRetryingFuture.java:77)
        at com.google.api.gax.retrying.CallbackChainRetryingFuture.<init>(CallbackChainRetryingFuture.java:62)
        at com.google.api.gax.retrying.ScheduledRetryingExecutor.createFuture(ScheduledRetryingExecutor.java:84)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.RetryingCallable.futureCall(RetryingCallable.java:61)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.RetryingCallable.futureCall(RetryingCallable.java:41)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable$1.futureCall(UnaryCallable.java:126)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.futureCall(UnaryCallable.java:87)
        at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreImpl.sendRequest(FirestoreImpl.java:327)
        at com.google.cloud.firestore.UpdateBuilder.commit(UpdateBuilder.java:608)
        at com.google.cloud.firestore.WriteBatch.commit(WriteBatch.java:41)
        at com.google.cloud.firestore.DocumentReference.delete(DocumentReference.java:335)
        at main.main(main.java:26)
```

I am using Gradle inside my Project with the following build:

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.10.0'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

I am writing the code that I used for deleting document:

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("./ServiceAccountKey.json");
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder().setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount)).build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
Firestore db ;
CollectionReference to_be_Deleted ;



db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();
ApiFuture<WriteResult> writeResult = db.collection("XXXXXX").document("WW4ovZ5amD56pxjd5NwY").delete();
System.out.println("Update time : " + writeResult.get().getUpdateTime());
```

I really need help regarding to this problem. I hope anyone can tell me my mistake.

Thank you Guys.

Comment: I am seeing a similar error. I'm querying a collection for documents that works when running in IntelliJ but fails in my built .jar with error: "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()".

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me now after doing the following. In IntelliJ I did *File* > *Invalidate Caches / Restart*. Then I rebuilt my **.jar** file and ran successfully.

I also deleted and rebuilt my .jar from scratch when I ran into this issue for a second time.

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar issue, I resolved it by excluding guava-jdk5 from my build.

```
// Exclude guava-jdk5 from the dependencies in gradle.
// guava-jdk5 uses older versions of classes that do not contain all required methods, as a later version of guava is in the project, excluding will mean it is used instead.
    configurations {
      all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module:'guava-jdk5'
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not fix the error for me. I am still seeing the error message. "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()"